# Azure KeyVault requests in multitenant environment

Tags: multi-tenant, azure-keyvault

I am working on multitenant ASP.NET application. We use Azure KeyVault to store secrets. It works quite well. We don't have any custom code written to handle keys.

Here is our code:

```
builder.AddAzureKeyVault(
            uri,
            credential,
            new KeyVaultSecretManager());
```

But let's say that we have 30 async services and all of them needs to have access to 200 secrets and there are 5 instances of each services. Then when we deploy the application we will have 30 * 200 * 5 requests (30 000) to the KV.

Here is my question: how do you handle this type of scenario? Split KeyVaults into different Key Vaults? Implements some providers with additional caching?

We wanted to store more information in the KeyVault and with the increasing number of services, and instances we will break the limit of requests to the KV.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

> We wanted to store more information in the KeyVault and with the increasing number of services, and instances we will break the limit of requests to the KV.

Because Key Vault has very [low rate limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/key-vault/general/service-limits), we have a few recommendations that should help:

1. Only store secrets in Key Vault. If you want to store general app configuration, use the Application Configuration (AppConfig) service/SDK. You can use both together for a combination of secrets and non-secrets. See https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/app-secrets-configuration/.
2. Caching is a good idea - in-memory or with solutions like Redis. See https://learn.microsoft.com/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-net/azure-key-vault-proxy/ for a very simple example of an in-memory cache.
3. Use separate Key Vaults for different applications. Vaults are relatively cheap and have no storage/lifetime cost - only egress costs. In this case, a separate vault per tenant may make more sense.

Also, since you mentioned you're developing a multi-tenant application, please see https://aka.ms/azsdk/blog/multi-tenant-guidance for necessary changes to our Identity SDK you may need to make.